# redirect with angularJs to other project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

My URL is like : http://localhost:3000/family/#/savings/subscribe/123456

in this page, I want to click on a button to redirect me into other page of another project made with backbone JS
I tried to add the needed URI with href- and ng-href `http://localhost:3000/admin#exemption` : but it always redirect me to `http://localhost:3000/family/#/admin#exemption`

```
   angular.module('app', ['ng', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularMoment', 'chart.js'])
 .config(fac['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
  .when('/index', {
        templateUrl: '/family/index',
        controller: 'IndexCtrl'
      })
  .when('/family/exemption', {
        templateUrl: 'exemption-search-view'
      })
```

when i gave the template of the needed page, I obtain the html view but the URI : `http://localhost:3000/family/#/admin#exemption`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in Angular, it redirects you to the same base in his URL, so if you want to change the base (which is /family/#/ in my case), it is like you are going to an external URL from the project so I had just added in my controller :

```
$window.location.href ='http://localhost:3000/admin#exemption' ;
```

I don't need any update in my '$routeProvider'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand the question, but if you wanto to avoid angular routing interception, you should add in your anchor target="_self".

```
<a ng-href="{{vm.logoutUrl}}" target="_self">Bye!</a>
```

Comment: To add, here it is in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location under "HTML link rewriting".

Answer (score 1):

If your other project is not part of your angular app, you should redirect to another URL.

Just use `<a href="http://localhost:yourOtherPort"></a>`.

ng-href is here to append the URL you're passing **after the hash in the URL**.

Comment: And if you want to delete your hashtag in the link, you can follow this link : https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting with the href (or any variant) try using a function in a controller which redirects you to the new url. Try something like this:

```
    // in your controller
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller('redirectCtrl', function($window, $location){

  var vm = this;

  vm.wizard = {
    anotherurl: "http://example.com",

    redirect: fnRedirect
  }

  return vm.wizard;

    function fnRedirect(link){
      //this way is useful if you try to redirect to an external URL
      $window.location = link;
      //this way is useful if you try to redirect to another route inside the same angular project
      $location.path(link);
    }
});
```

...and in your html...

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="redirectCtrl as rc">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="rc.anotherurl" />
    <a href="" data-ng-click="rc.redirect(rc.anotherurl)">Redirect me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you recreate the action of `href` ? Instead of using `href="path-to-the-other-app"`, you need to have a controller with a dedicated method and handle a link with an `ng-click` ?! I do not agree with you.